# How can I calculate a relative measure of change for data series that can include zero?

Tags: descriptive-statistics, percentage, measurement

I have a series of data points representing the number of OKs for a test. For each data point, I want to calculate by how much its value changed compared to the preceding value, and I need this measure to be relative rather than absolute, as it makes it easier to understand and to compare different series of the same kind.

I thought I could use a simple

${\displaystyle {\text{Percentage change}}={\frac {\Delta V}{V_{1}}}={\frac {V_{2}-V_{1}}{V_{1}}}\times 100\%}$

But the obvious problem with this approach is that the number of OKs can often be 0, and a division by zero is not possible.

Is there a better way to obtain a relative measure of change in this scenario? I am fairly new to statistics and wonder if there is a measure of index I am not yet aware of that would be more appropriate.

Answer (score 6):

The fact that you are interested in relative change doesn’t mean that you should compute a measure of relative change from the raw data and then analyze that.  It is much better to analyze the raw data, possibly covariate-adjusted for the initial value. (This doesn’t address your wish to adjust for the continuously moving *preceding* value though).  Percent changes are **not** easier to understand, because they are [asymmetric measures](https://hbiostat.org/bbr/change), e.g. a 100% increase is offset by a 50% decrease.

Were there no zeros in your data you could do a relative analysis by sampling logging the raw values and analyzing all those logs, converting estimates of interest to fold change by taking anti-logs of regression coefficients, for example.

Comparing different series on % change basis may hide important effects such as the effect of the starting value.

When in doubt, graph and analyze the raw data.

Comment: Thanks for your insights. I've learned valuable things going through your answer. To clarify:
--- I focus on the change since the preceding datapoint as I want to see if the number of OKs has changed compared to the last execution, rather than comparing it to the first execution that might have taken place months ago
--- I prefer a relative measure to rank tests with varying numbers of OKs, so that those with the strongest change will come on top
--- I've used graphs, but now aim to automate the process to highlight significant changes in OKs.
Any further suggestions given these points?

Comment: ...and to graph the data I would suggest you put V1 on the x-axis and DeltaV on the y-axis and see what pattern your data points form. Hopefully, they do form a pattern!

Comment: Any measure that involves summarizing two measurements with one number (by subtract, ratio, % change, …) makes assumptions such as the variable being perfectly transformed before doing the computation.  I would rather depict “change” by looking at whole trajectories and slopes over time.  You can even do this using semiparametric ordinal models that only use the ordering of outcome levels.